# PyroCMS user registration error

Tags: php, laravel, pyrocms, user-registration

So I'm a newbie at laravel framework and PyroCMS, I recently install PyroCMS and go to `mydomain.com/register` to try the registration function and I got the following error, but no idea how to solve it.

#### Error code:

```
}

/**
 * Convert the given string to upper-case.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public static function upper($value)
{
    return mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Highlighted line
}

/**
 * Convert the given string to title case.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public static function title($value)
{
    return mb_convert_case($value, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
}
```

And

```
public static function substr($string, $start, $length = null)
{
    return mb_substr($string, $start, $length, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Which the line `return mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');` and `return mb_substr($string, $start, $length, 'UTF-8');` is highlighted with an error log `expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

How can I solve it?

---

#### More info:

Error file: `pyrocms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php`

Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: How are you calling `upper($value)` because `$value` is an array, that is what the error says, so seeing just that code is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may or may not want to do something like this

```
public static function upper($value)
{
   if(is_array($value)){
         foreach($value as &$item){
             $item = self::upper($item); //recursive
         }
         return $value;
   }

    return mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
}
```

This will recursively call `upper` when it's an array and the effect will be that it will uppercase everything in `$value`.  This may or may not be what you want.

Chances are you are passing the wrong data to this method.

To pass the right data you would do something like

```
$value['key'] = Class::upper($value['key']);
```

But I have no idea what value `key` should be, and I don't even know what class these methods reside in `Class`.  I don't use `laravel` and I never heard of `PyroCMS` before.

If I used every framework that came along i would spend my days learning frameworks and not building them.  I don't use `laravel` because I don't like the syntax `blade` uses, I am not a fan of `query` builders, probably these can be replaced but we already have everything build in a different framework.  So there is no need to customize it to work the way I want it to when we already have a solution that works just fine.

That said, I do know PHP, I know it quite well in fact.

Comment: Then how about I got the same error (`mb_substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`) for the code `public static function substr($string, $start, $length = null)
    {
        return mb_substr($string, $start, $length, 'UTF-8');
    }`?

Comment: Then you can do the same thing for that, but again this may not be what you want, because a string is a string and an array is an array, and you may not want to modify the whole array but only 1 element.  I have no way to know that so I cant help you decide if you should send 1 element from the array or change it to handle arrays as I did above.

Comment: I have no idea, its one of the default module called `user` for pyrocms